# How can I give another user access to my Azure portal resources?

Tags: azure, portal

I am trying to give other users access to my resources in the Azure portal. I am trying to add them as a Contributor, but it seems like they are not able to see the resources when they login to the Azure portal.

Here's the access control list for the VM:
[image]

Any ideas why they can't see the resource when they login to the portal?
They are a Contributor.

Comment: are they logging to the same portal? I mean, to the portal where resources exist? Also, did they try hard refreshing webpage? Did they try another browser?

Comment: I have seen where you also need to log out and back in. I might also suggest setting up groups in your subscription for easier management.

One other thing to know is if they have multiple subscriptions that they may need to select the correct subscription from the top right of the portal.

Comment: @Jonathan The top-right selection is the AAD directory, not the subscription. When you select one, all subscriptions that are associated to that directory are shown. But you are correct, that could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a user to an Azure subscription, s/he is also added to the directory if s/he isn't already there. This is considered an "invitation" that must be accepted before the user can get access. Tell the person to check their email, if this is the first time the email address has been added to a subscription in the directory. (Note that personal subscriptions are usually created along with a new directory whereas company subscriptions are usually in the company's directory.)

After accepting the invitation, s/he will need to switch to the directory before the subscription will be visible. You can do that in the top-right, like Juunas mentioned in the comment above. Here's a link to the directory switcher: https://portal.azure.com/#menu/account.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to reproduce-
As owner:
Go to Resource Group you want to give access to:
Go to IAM:
Go to 'Add ROLE ASSIGNMENTS'
Search the name you want to give access to:
Select the Role (Contributor in your case)
Click Add and they will recieve an email.